# Spring scheduled task on Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I just tried deploying my Java/Spring solution on Google App Engine and when I try to access one of the REST services(I guess that triggers the application to start running) I see an exception in the log.

This seems to be related to my scheduled task. I know that thread management is limited on GAE(generally a good thing) and I know they have something called CRON for scheduling, but I would really like to use scheduled tasks from Spring. Is there any way to do that?

Exception:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:484)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:698)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:55)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:136)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:675)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:572)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:600)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:566)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Executors.java:695)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(ConcurrentTaskScheduler.java:203)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.scheduleTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:318)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:284)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:162)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:203)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:133)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:511)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:274)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: is your app running on a Frontend instance?